# What is a cotopos?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

This question is comprised of two parts, one particular and one general.

---

In the nLab page on [base change](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/base+change), one finds the following statement:

> For $f\colon X\to Y$ a [morphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/morphism) in a [category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category) $\mathcal{C}$ with [pullbacks](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pullback), there is an induced [functor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functor) $$f^{*}\colon\mathcal{C}_{/Y}\to\mathcal{C}_{/X}$$ of [over-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/over+category).
> This is the *base change* morphism. If $\mathcal{C}$ is a [topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topos), then this refines to an [essential geometric morphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/essential+geometric+morphism) $$(f_{!}\dashv f^{*}\dashv f_{*})\colon\mathcal{C}_{/X}\to\mathcal{C}_{/Y}.$$ The [dual](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/duality) concept is [cobase change](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cobase+change).

In the dual case, if $\mathcal{C}$ has pushouts, then we have an induced functor
$$
f^{*}
\colon
\mathcal{C}_{X/}
\to
\mathcal{C}_{Y/}
$$
and an adjunction
$$
(f_{*}\dashv f^{*})
\colon
\mathcal{C}_{Y/}
\rightleftarrows
\mathcal{C}_{X/}.
$$
**Particular Question.** What is the dual condition on $\mathcal{C}$ for which this adjunction extends to a triple adjunction
$$
(f_{*}\dashv f^{*}\dashv f_{!})
\colon
\mathcal{C}_{Y/}
\underset{\to}{\rightleftarrows}
\mathcal{C}_{X/}
$$
between $\mathcal{C}_{Y/}$ and $\mathcal{C}_{X/}$?

---

**General Question.** What is the dual notion of a topos? Such a notion, call it a *cotopos* for brevity, might perhaps behave in the following ways:

- For cotopoi, Cartesian closedness is replaced by [coCartesian coclosedness](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cocartesian+closed+category).
- Slices of cotopoi may fail to be cotopoi, but coslices of cotopoi are always cotopoi.
- Sheaves are to topoi as cosheaves are to cotopoi (Maybe. Should this indeed be the case?)
- (Etc.)

Comment: Note: the general question above has been asked before by [David Corfield on the nForum](https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/3193/cotopos/)

Comment: Isn't this a straightforward exercise in dualisation? A cotopos is simply a category whose opposite is a topos. With which part are you having difficulty?

Comment: @varkor: perhaps Emily has some other desideratum implicitly in mind, which makes “category whose opposite is a topos” an unsatisfactory answer?  If so, that should really be made explicit, otherwise this isn’t much of a question as you say!

Comment: By the way, the category doesn't have to be a topos for a morphism to give rise to an adjoint triple in this way. It just has to be locally cartesian closed.

Comment: In hindsight, I think I was asking the wrong question: I was a bit off-put by the need that $\mathcal{C}$ had to be a topos for such a triple adjunction to hold. Locally Cartesian closedness makes much more sense. (I was also wondering why are cotopoi not so common while topoi are ubiquitous, but that makes sense: one notion excludes the other (i.e. the opposite of a co/topos can't be a co/topos), and one is already extremely common, so the other must not be so.)

Comment: Thanks everyone! @ReidBarton, Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine, varkor

Comment: In case you haven’t seen it yet, Grothendieck studies (pseudo) cotopos in [pursuing stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.01000)

Comment: @scritoriano I hadn't seen it, thanks!